# Gnome lockscreen does not allow to type in the password

Tags: gnome, 20.04, suspend, lock-screen, gnome-classic

I have the following problem - after updating to Ubuntu 20.04 and configuring gnome, the laptop goes into suspend mode when closing the lid. In 95% of the time, the lockscreen behaves as expected and let's me type in my password. But sometimes (I haven't figured out a trigger for that yet), the screen does not open the field to type in the password on mouse or key activity. The mouse works as expected, and the keyboard is responsive (for instance, the speaker mute/louder buttons work). The menu point `PowerOff/Logout` exists but instead of the ususal three choices `Log Out/PowerOff/Suspend`, it only has the `Suspend` option. The only way to get out of this situation is to restart the computer.
Any suggestion how to prevent this situation?

Update: It hasn't happened now for two months, so I thought an update got rid of this problem. Turns out today, this thought was wrong. Unsurprisingly, I forgot to test what Fedon Kadifeli suggested. Meh.

Comment: Did you try to press Ctrl+Alt+F1 and / or Ctrl+Alt+F2 instead of restarting?

Comment: No. The problem is obviously that this problem is not consistently reproducible without knowing the trigger, so I cannot check immediately if that is of any help, But I will think of it (I hope) next time this happens.